# returning an array in json using php?

Tags: php, json, mobile, while-loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $response = array(
        'id' => $row['true'],
        'username' => $row['username'],
        'image'=>$row['image']
    );
    echo json_encode($response);

        }
```

im trying to send like 20 rows back to a mobile client using json, is this the way to do it, im not sure if this makes sense!! espcially in a while loop.

Comment: sorry if its a dumb question, but im so curious

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an array and json_encode it after your loop:

```
$responses = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $response = array(
        'id' => $row['true'],
        'username' => $row['username'],
        'image'=>$row['image']
    );
    $responses[] = $response;
}
echo json_encode($responses);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it looks so clean, can i just ask why did you do that way, im just so curious hehe :))

Comment: +1 Too fast! Also, you can just use `$responses[] = array(` instead of that extra line at the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: Because that's the proper way: building an array and then json-encoding it.

Comment: @Drackir: True, but IMO it's more readable with the separate variable.

Comment: @pingpong: It's because instead of outputting an array as a json encoded array, you were outputting each element individually as a single string, which is not the same thing and will not parse correctly.

Comment: @pingpong: Fyi, you can also directly put $row in your array (I'd use mysql_fetch_assoc in this case though so you do not get numeric indexes, too)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Not in this case, since the array keys and the table columns are not 1-1

Comment: True, but maybe be could change his JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$responses = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $response[] = array(
        'id' => $row['true'],
        'username' => $row['username'],
        'image'=>$row['image']
    );
}
echo json_encode($response);
```